# E/PDFView: load pdf error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext, pdfview

DETAILS : My application creates a pdf using data previously entered. The PDF is created in the application itself using :

```
//PDF GENERATOR
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.3'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

I view that PDF in the same Activity using :

```
//PDF VIEW
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
```

The code for that is as follows :

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Zomato/Receipts");
file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), "Reciept.pdf");

pdfView.fromFile(file).load();

boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
}

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument); 
document.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);

float[] columnWidth = {110, 550, 140}; 
Table table1 = new Table(columnWidth);


//Table1------- 01
table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Hello Welcome")).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE));

table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("This is the PDF Data").setBold().setFontSize(14f)
        .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));

table1.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Address : " + Common.currentCompany.getAddress()).setBold().setFontSize(8f).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));

document.add(table1);
document.close();
textView.setText(R.string.downloaded_message);

}
```

This code works on phone Samsung M31 but it does not work on Redmi Y2 and Oppo. When I run this code on these phones I get the following error :

```
E/PDFView: load pdf error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Please help. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time.

Comment: The error says "No such file or directory". So, have you checked `file.exists()` before `pdfView.fromFile(file).load()`?

Comment: You are trying to load the pdf file before you create one.

Comment: You are trying to .create a directory after you tried to load a file from it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. So here is the solution. I replaced this part of the code :

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Zomato/Receipts");
file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), "Reciept.pdf");

pdfView.fromFile(file).load();

boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
success = folder.mkdirs();
}

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

With this :

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    File folder = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DOCUMENTS);
    Log.e("Tag", folder.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + epoch + ".pdf");
```

And I shifted the PDFView to the bottom below:

```
document.close();
pdfView.fromFile(file).load();
```

Comment: if(!folder.mkdirs()) return; Display also a toast to inform the user.